# Teams Meeting Integration in ,Net Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, clientcredential

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid) | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events
I want to generate link of teams. Can I generate link using token generated by

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};
var result = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes);
```

I have use username password flow but that flow is not recommended as per official documentation
Is there any way to create teams meeting using graph API without usernamepassword flow.

Comment: pls kindly try my code snippet and let me know if it didn't work for you.

Comment: Mayur2402 :  We would like to use device code flow to generate access token. Which will be use to generate event in teams calendar. learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/…. We need to send notification to user code received by AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode this method

Comment: thanks for informing me about it and since what I post is not suitable for your scenario, I've deleted it.

Comment: Thanks tinu wang for your help I have found solution to generate token using aquiretokenonbehalfof() function